# why is my while loop not detecting inputs from cin?

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector<int> inputs;
    int x;
    cout << "Enter values:";
    cin >> x;

    while(cin>>x)
        inputs.insert(inputs.end(),{x});


    for(int i=0; i<inputs.size();i++)
        cout << inputs[i]<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried many methods to try to get my while loop to detect the inputs but when it runs and I put in the values it doesn't print out the contents of the vector.

I have first tried separating `inputs.insert(inputs.end(),{x});` from the while loop and just doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector<int> inputs;
    int x;
    cout << "Enter values:";
    cin >> x;

    while(cin>>x)
        x;
    
    inputs.insert(inputs.end(),{x});

    for(int i=0; i<inputs.size();i++)
        cout << inputs[i]<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That doesn't work either. I've also tried removing the brackets but that also isn't the issue. The while loop shouldn't be breaking if all I'm typing is integers. I know if it was a string it would detect the spaces and then stop.

I apologize if this is a repetitive post but I really did try looking for similar issues and can't seem to figure out what's happening.

Comment: You may want to replace `inputs.insert()` with `inputs.push_back()`.  Usually appending the data, then sorting is faster than trying an insert sort.

Comment: Did you try filling the vector using `push_back()`?

Comment: Your 2nd example only irritates the User because you don't do anything with the data that they entered.  The `inputs.insert()` after the `while` loop only inserts the last value that the User entered.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  I did originally use push_back() but switched to insert because push_back() only took in one element at a time. I thought it would be faster this way.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews if I use push_back with the while (cin >> x) it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I tried your original code and the inputs were received and added to the vector. How are you "ending" your input? (I typed a "q" as an invalid integer input.) Also, the first `cin >> x;` does nothing of lasting effect - that input will be lost/ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `cin >> x;` after `cout << "Enter values:";`. That is capturing the first entry and not inserting it into the vector. I would recommend using `.push_back()` as well, but I've left it to how you originally had that handling. Otherwise, this is working as I would expect it to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector<int> inputs;
    int x;
    cout << "Enter values:";

    while (cin >> x)
        inputs.insert(inputs.end(), { x });


    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++)
        cout << inputs[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

[image: example]

Comment: the way it's compiling is weird. It only working when you shift enter the input values, otherwise it doesn't work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't know you had to type a non integer to terminate the while loop. Do you know how to do it without having to ask for a non-integer to terminate?

Comment: @binteuler what other condition did you have in mind? Currently, the failure for formatted input is your *only* break condition, as *you* wrote. If you have a different condition in addition to that, specify it as part of the continuation mechanic of the while loop.

Comment: My knowledge is limited as I am a beginner. The only method I can think of atm is to just use getline() since that will terminate after the user presses enter and then convert the string into ints. Any other method would be out of my scope. Thanks again.

Comment: @binteuler [Your posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70624810/edit) needs a lot more very specific details of expected input form, expected code behavior, and expected output. Be **precise** . People should not have to search a raft of comments to filter out details that should be included there.

Comment: My question *was* specific. How was I supposed to know that the reason why it was not detecting input was because I needed to type a non-integer to stop the while loop? What part of my question wasn't specific?